# Sencha Touch 2x Packaging

Tags: extjs, touch, packaging

I've got multiple packages that I'm including into an app.js - I'd like to break the app.js to two files: one file that would load a single package, then load the a secondary file that would include the rest of the packages.

Has anyone used CMD to manage this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use: [Ext.Loader](https://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Loader)

```
Ext.require()
Ext.Loader.setPath()
Ext.Loader.syncPath()
Ext.Loader.loadScriptFile()
```

Other than that Modern ExtJS [Dynamic Loading](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.4.0/guides/dynamic_package_loading.html) should be a good starting point: